# Notation for an optimization function that receives a vector of pairs

Tags: optimization

In my optimization problem there are elements consisting of a time and a value, i.e. $(t_0, v_0)$.
These pairs are stored in a vector $v = [(t_0, v_0), (t_1, v_1), ... , (t_n, v_n)]$.
The vector $v$ serves as an input to an optimization function $f$ that computes a cost value from the input.

Is it mathematically common to say that $V$ is the set of all possible variants of $v$ and thus define $f$ as $f : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Since no one else has answered, I'd say it looks alright to me. Though I would probably say $f:\mathbb{R}^{n \times 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, if indeed $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems correct, but I would suggest two minor improvements:

- Rearrange the pairs in a $(n+1)\times 2$ matrix
  $$
  M = \begin{bmatrix}
  t_0 & v_0\\
  \vdots & \vdots\\
  t_n & v_n
  \end{bmatrix},
  $$
  so that you can replace $V$ with $\mathbb{R}^{(n+1)\times 2}$, as suggested by user @Nachiket in a comment.
- Avoid using the letter $v$ for this matrix, because it conflicts with the common notation that $v$ is the vector with entries $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$.